# Passing associated models to actions in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a hard time understanding the logic behind the way EmberJS deals with passing associated models as action arguments.

In a template I have the following:

```
{{#each account.people as |person|}}
  <p>{{person.name}}</p>

  {{#each person.relationships as |relationship|}}
    <p {{action "doStuff" person relationship relationship.otherPerson}}>
      {{relationship.otherPerson.name}}
    </p>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

The weird thing is that in the `doStuff` action

- `person` is a Model
- `relationship` is a Model
- `otherPerson` is a Promise

I don't know if it's an expected behavior and how to deal the right way with it if so.

*Note: This is a contrived example and passing all those arguments is weird, it's just to illustrate my point.*

*Note2: I'm aware I could use `Promise.resolve(otherPerson)` in my action but I don't see why I should use a low-level call like this.*

*Note3: My question is "Since I'm accessing `otherPerson.name` why is `otherPerson` still a promise to be resolved when I'm in the action? Is there a way to always have a resolved model without doing hacky stuff?"*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the actual question here is, but...

```
relationship.otherPerson
```

is a promise because Ember Data lazy loads relationships.  HTMLBars templates are able to understand and wait for resolution on relationships, but they're still promise-like under the hood.

If you use `{async: false}` in your model definition
e.g.

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
  author: belongsTo('person', {async:false})
});
```

This is telling Ember Data that the data is already loaded, and that it can treat the relationship as synchronous.  No promise is returned when accessing `relationship.otherPerson`. It does require you to already have the relationship data loaded, either side-loaded in you route or from being confident it's already in the Store.

It is a bit confusing how Ember allows you to happily access relationships with dot syntax in the template, but in code you need to treat it as a promise.

Comment: I know it's an async relationship but I would expect the promise to be resolved before being passed as action argument without having to "manipulate" the low-level notion of a promise here. Since I'm accessing the `otherPerson.name` I'd expect `otherPerson` to be resolved at this point.

Comment: It may be resolved, but it's still a promise. Even resolved, you'll need to access the value through a `.then(name =>` function.  Think about doing `new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(1))` - this doesn't return 1, but an immediately resolve promise object.

Comment: I know but as I said in Note 2 I would expect not to have to deal with promises manipulation in this context. If it's not possible it's not but that bothers me anyway ^^ Thanks ;)